# Force the Kivy Loader to use a specific set of headers?

Tags: python, api, kivy, urllib

I am running into an issue where the API I am trying to use to access some images requires a reference header. I am able to access these images using `requests` and `urllib`, but have no clue how to make Kivy's Loader use these headers without making intrusive changes to the code.

[kivy/loader.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/loader.py) is where the magic happens. I know *how* to add headers to it by changing that file, but I wanted to see if there was a better way to do this beyond hacking up the original library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you can't. There is however a pull request on Github that adds that functionality.

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7669